# Maps Android API: Authorization failure

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

There are many questions similar to mine. i went over them all (i hope). Also i think i'm doing everything OK. `Maps v2` worked until last update of `Google Services` to `Rev 25`

I'm getting:

```
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure

Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
```

[image: Checked]

```
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: AIzaSyB...
```

[image: Key ok checked]

Key matches. next:

```
Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 87:60:41:37...;com.example.example
```

[image: Cert Ok]
Certificate match

So everything matches but i still getting `Authorization failure`

`AndroidManifest`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="7571000" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

gradle-app:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
}
```

Also i recompiled and re-installed the app multiple times

Comment: updated question, thanks for the fast response

Comment: `manifest-aplication`

Comment: delete older key and generate new key.Helps!!

Comment: Add the manifest as whole please.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the version update only causes this? Have you tried a simple revert to the old version to ensure that this causes the error?

Comment: It's a joke. @MD it worked. It drove me crazy . im annoyed that this was the solution /-:. please write it as an answer that i would be able to accept it (even though it's a one liner it still a very helpful one liner)

Comment: @royB ohhhhhhh very gud!!!! my comment is just like `playing chess in the dark`So it's not an answer. Just suggestion... but wait i'll post it

Comment: @MD lol, it seems that you know what you are talking about (-;. Anyhow thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Delete older key and generate new key. Hope it helps!!
```

The answer is only based on comment.